# PluginError: node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp

`/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg ENOENT`

The `minify-images` plugin can't work when i want to compress my blog images.

```js
const gulp = require('gulp')
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css')
const htmlmin = require('gulp-html-minifier-terser')
const htmlclean = require('gulp-htmlclean')
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin')
// gulp-tester (如果使用 gulp-tester,把下面的//去掉)
const terser = require('gulp-terser');

// babel (如果不是使用bebel,把下面兩行註釋掉)
// const uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
// const babel = require('gulp-babel')

// minify js - babel（ 如果不是使用bebel,把下面註釋掉）
// gulp.task('compress', () =>
//   gulp.src(['./public/**/*.js', '!./public/**/*.min.js'])
//     .pipe(babel({
//       presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
//     }))
//     .pipe(uglify().on('error', function (e) {
//       console.log(e)
//     }))
//     .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'))
// )

// minify js - gulp-tester (如果使用 gulp-tester,把下面前面的//去掉)
gulp.task('compress', () =>
  gulp.src(['./public/**/*.js', '!./public/**/*.min.js'])
    .pipe(terser())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'))
)


// css
gulp.task('minify-css', () => {
  return gulp.src('./public/**/*.css')
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'))
})

// 壓縮 public 目錄內 html
gulp.task('minify-html', () => {
  return gulp.src('./public/**/*.html')
    .pipe(htmlclean())
    .pipe(htmlmin({
      removeComments: true, // 清除 HTML 註釋
      collapseWhitespace: true, // 壓縮 HTML
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true, // 省略布爾屬性的值 <input checked="true"/> ==> <input />
      removeEmptyAttributes: true, // 刪除所有空格作屬性值 <input id="" /> ==> <input />
      removeScriptTypeAttributes: true, // 刪除 <script> 的 type="text/javascript"
      removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true, // 刪除 <style> 和 <link> 的 type="text/css"
      minifyJS: true, // 壓縮頁面 JS
      minifyCSS: true, // 壓縮頁面 CSS
      minifyURLs: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'))
})

// 壓縮 public/uploads 目錄內圖片
gulp.task('minify-images', async () => {
  gulp.src('./public/img/**/*.jpg')
    .pipe(imagemin({
      optimizationLevel: 5, // 類型：Number  預設：3  取值範圍：0-7（優化等級）
      progressive: true, // 類型：Boolean 預設：false 無失真壓縮jpg圖片
      interlaced: true, // 類型：Boolean 預設：false 隔行掃描gif進行渲染
      multipass: true // 類型：Boolean 預設：false 多次優化svg直到完全優化
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/img'))
})

// 執行 gulp 命令時執行的任務
gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel(
  'compress', 'minify-css', 'minify-html', 'minify-images'
))
// gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel(
//     'compress', 'minify-css', 'minify-html'
//   ))
```

```
[00:46:25] Starting 'default'...
[00:46:25] Starting 'compress'...
[00:46:25] Starting 'minify-css'...
[00:46:25] Starting 'minify-html'...
[00:46:25] Starting 'minify-images'...
[00:46:25] Finished 'minify-images' after 22 ms
[00:46:26] The following tasks did not complete: default, compress, minify-css, minify-html
[00:46:26] Did you forget to signal async completion?

node:internal/process/promises:245
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^
PluginError: spawn /Users/Zkp/仓库/myweb/blog-cn/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Domain instance at:
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (node:domain:520:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.onerror (/Users/Zkp/仓库/myweb/blog-cn/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:640:52)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (node:domain:470:12)
```